# Finding sum of convergent alternating series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I am not sure how to find the sum of this [series](https://latex.codecogs.com/gif.latex?%5Cinline&space;%5Csum_%7Bn=0%7D%5E%7B%5Cinfty%7D%7B(-1)%5En%5Ccdot&space;(2n+1)%5E%7B-1%7D%7D%22%20title=)

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{(-1)^n\cdot(2n+1)^{-1}}$$

I know it converges due to the alternating series test because the function is decreasing over its domain and the limit as $n$ approachs infinite is zero. However, I don't know what method to use to compute the finite value it converges to.

Also I know the answer is $\pi/4$ because Wolframalpha but I want to know how. Thanks.

Comment: Write down the Taylor series for $\arctan x$ and use $x = 1$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be shown from the Taylor series

$$ \arctan x = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n \frac{x^{2n+1}}{2n+1} $$

Letting $x=1$

$$ \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n \frac{1}{2n+1} = \arctan 1 = \frac{\pi}{4} $$

For a proof of this, infer from the geometric series
$$ \frac{1}{1+x^2} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n x^{2n} $$

Then integrate both sides

Comment: Thank you! I forgot about Taylor series!

Answer (score 2):

If your interest is in *computing* the value (and you're interested in more alternating series than just this one), then you may be interested in [*series acceleration*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Series_acceleration) techniques. The basic method for accelerating alternating series, Euler's method, has a great 'heuristic' derivation in terms of operators:

Consider two operators: the *shift operator* $E$ that, when applied to the element $a_n$ of a sequence, produces the element $Ea_n = a_{n+1}$; and the *difference* operator $\Delta$ that gives the difference between the next and current elements, $\Delta a_n=a_{n+1}-a_n$.  Then these operators satisfy the conceptual relation $E=1+\Delta$ (where strictly speaking here '$1$' is actually the identity operator).

Now, the series $\sum_n (-1)^na_n$ can be written as $\sum_n (-1)^nE^na_0$; each term in the sequence $a_n$ is obtained by applying the shift operator $E$ $n$ times to the first term. But this 'looks' like a geometric series, so we can formally write $\sum_n (-1)^na_n$ $=\sum_n(-1)^nE^na_0$ $=\frac1{1+E}a_0$.  Now, substitute $E=1+\Delta$ into this to get $\sum_n(-1)^na_n = \frac1{2+\Delta}a_0$. And expand again using the geometric series : $\frac1{2+\Delta}a_0$ $= \frac12\frac1{1+\Delta/2}a_0$ $=\frac12\sum_n(-1)^n\left(\frac\Delta2\right)^na_0$ $= \sum_n\frac{(-1)^n}{2^{n+1}}\Delta^na_0$.

This is all heuristic and needs to be rigorously justified, of course, but it turns out that that justification can in fact be given; the transformed series will converge if the original series does, and converge to the same value. What's more, it will typically converge much faster; in the case of your series where $a_n=\frac1{2n+1}$ it's easy to show by induction that $\Delta^ia_n = (-1)^i\dfrac{(2\cdot 4\cdot\ldots\cdot (2i))}{(2n+1)(2n+3)\ldots(2n+2i+1)}$ and so $\Delta^i a_0 = (-1)^i\dfrac{(2\cdot4\cdot\ldots\cdot(2i))}{1\cdot3\cdot\ldots\cdot (2i+1)}$ $=(-1)^i\dfrac{2^2\cdot4^2\cdot\ldots\cdot(2i)^2}{(2i+1)!}$ $=(-1)^i\dfrac{2^{2i}(i!)^2}{(2i+1)!}$.  This turns out to be roughly proportional to $i^{-1/2}$ as $i\to\infty$ and so the convergence of the 'transformed' series $\frac\pi4=\sum_n\dfrac{2^{n-1}(n!)^2}{(2n+1)!}$ is basically geometric, giving you roughly one bit of precision per term.